# How to write Cordova plugin in Swift?

Tags: cordova, swift

I converted existing custom plugin to Swift language:

*(located under `Plugins/CustomPluginInSwift.swift`)*

```
import Foundation

class CustomPluginInSwift : CDVPlugin {    

    func getSettings(command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand) {        

        println("CustomPluginInSwift :: getSettings is called")               

        var pluginResult = CDVPluginResult(status: CDVCommandStatus_OK)
        commandDelegate.sendPluginResult(pluginResult, callbackId:command.callbackId)
    }
}
```

And I have two problems:

- `CDVPlugin` not found
- Javascript doesn't see plugin: `CustomPluginInSwift`:

> CDVPlugin class CustomPluginInSwift (pluginName: CustomPluginInSwift) does not exist

I left `config.xml` the same but it doesn't work as expected.

Where is my problem?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As is mentioned you have to add a bridging-header.h file which contains

```
#import <Cordova/CDV.h>
```

Also you need to add the bridging header's path in XCode project properties->Build Settings->Objective-C Bridging Header. For example:

```
your-app-name/plugins/com.plugin.example/bridging-header.h
```

Additionally, in order for Objective-C to see the same plugin class name, you need to add an @objc mapping to the class declaration. It can be the same as the swift class name itself, or something different. In this example, "HWPCustomPluginInSwift" will be what Objective-C (and Javascript) will end up seeing:

```
@objc(HWPCustomPluginInSwift) class CustomPluginInSwift : CDVPlugin {
```

and then your feature node in config.xml file should look like this:

```
<feature name="CustomPluginInSwift">
    <param name="ios-package" value="HWPCustomPluginInSwift" />
</feature>
```

Comment: I think its better solution

Comment: It should be noted that the current Cordova release  (4.3.0) does not seem to generate a Swift-compatible XCode project. If you're using the Cordova CLI, you may need to download an edge version to get your project to build properly. See: https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/pull/133

Comment: Currently I am using hook to enable swift support in xCode project https://github.com/cowbell/cordova-plugin-geofence/blob/20de72b918c779511919f7e38d07721112d4f5c8/hooks/add_swift_support.js . It is good to know they are working on built-in solution.

Comment: I wrote tutorial on how to do this with the latest XCode 8.2 / Swift 3 here: https://medium.com/modus-create-front-end-development/writing-a-cordova-plugin-in-swift-3-for-ios-e314acf68a47#.1xxihldrj

Comment: also make sure to add `@objc(getSettings:)` in front of your swift method definition! Otherwise you would have to label the action in js as  "getSettingsCommand"

Answer (score 11):

> `CDVPlugin` not found

When you created swift file 1st time, Xcode asks you to generate

`<your app name>-Bridging-Header.h` header with empty content:

```
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//
```

In this header add:

```
#import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>
```

After that clean your project.  If you don't have this header - create it.

---

> CDVPlugin class CustomPluginInSwift (pluginName: CustomPluginInSwift) does not exist

**[Step 1]**

Right, because Swift uses `_TtC` (*Type To Class*) prefix and class index with following template:

```
_TtC8<AppName><index#><PluginName>
```

How to know what is proper index?

**[Step 2]**

When you initiate instance of `CustomPluginInSwift` class, like:

```
var temp:CustomPluginInSwift = CustomPluginInSwift()
```

, Swift will add *new class name* to `<AppName>-Swift.h` header. The problem is that this header you can't see in your project.

**How to find it?**

- Go to xCode -> Window -> Organazer -> "Project Tabs"
- Select your project
- copy "Derived Data" path (for me: `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<AppName>-hbgwavxfqvhwxzagxhgzjvsdrkjk`)
- Go to console and run `cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<AppName>-hbgwavxfqvhwxzagxhgzjvsdrkjk`
- run after: `cd Build/Intermediates/<App name>.build/Debug-iphoneos/<App name>.build/DerivedSources/`

You can find file named: `<App name>-Swift.h` there with following content:

```
/* ... */

SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC8Wanameet14CustomPluginInSwift")
@interface CustomPluginInSwift : CDVPlugin
- (void)getSettings:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command;
- (instancetype)initWithWebView:(UIWebView *)theWebView OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end

/* ... */
```

So we got proper name: `_TtC8Wanameet14CustomPluginInSwift`

**[Step 3]**

Now, go to `config.xml` and change from:

```
<feature name="CustomPluginInSwift">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CustomPluginInSwift" />
</feature>
```

to:

```
<feature name="MeeterCalendar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="_TtC8Wanameet14CustomPluginInSwift" />
</feature>
```

---

Thats all,

Hope it will save time,

tested on `cordova 3.5` + `xCode6.1`

---

### examples

Consider you have `Plugins` folder in your project (generated by Cordova).

We create New swift file `MyPlugin.swift` with following content:

```
@objc(HWPMyPlugin) class MyPlugin : CDVPlugin { // see @tsubik answer
 /* ... */
}
```

**method example where we parse javascript request and immediately return answer:**

```
func someMethod(command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand){
    
    println("MyPlugin :: someMethod is called")
    
    let callbackId:String = command.callbackId
    
    var obj:AnyObject = command.arguments[0] as AnyObject!
    
    var eventStructure:AnyObject = obj["eventStructure"]
    var eventId:String = eventStructure["_id"] as AnyObject! as String        
    
    println("MyPlugin :: someMethod :: _id:  \(eventId) ")
        
    self.commandDelegate.runInBackground({
        // 'jw' is some class          
        var data:NSData = jw.toJson()
        var str:String = jw.toJsonString(data)
        
        
        var obj:JSONObject = jw.getJSONObjectFromNSData(data)
        println("sampleList as String: \(str)")
        
        var pluginResult:CDVPluginResult = CDVPluginResult(status: CDVCommandStatus_OK, messageAsDictionary: obj)
        self.commandDelegate.sendPluginResult(pluginResult, callbackId:command.callbackId)
    })

}
```

**method example where we return empty callabck and after some time return answer:**

I used a lot this method form when you try to fetch some data on native side by async way:

```
protocol AccountLoaderListenerItf {
   func onAccountsDone(data:NSData)
} 

@objc(HWPMyPlugin) class MyPlugin : CDVPlugin, AccountLoaderListenerItf { 
 
  var mCalendarAccountsCallbackContext:String?

  
func getCalendarAccounts( command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand ){
    println("MyPlugin :: getCalendarAccounts is called")
    
    self.mCalendarAccountsCallbackContext = command.callbackId
    
    self.commandDelegate.runInBackground({            
        
        var all:AccountLoaderListenerItf = self
        
        var accounts = MyAccounts(accLoader: all)
        
        accounts.populateFromCalendars()            
        
        var pluginResult:CDVPluginResult = CDVPluginResult(status:CDVCommandStatus_NO_RESULT)
        pluginResult.setKeepCallbackAsBool(true)
        self.commandDelegate.sendPluginResult(pluginResult, callbackId:command.callbackId)            
    })
} // func

 /* .... */

func onAccountsDone(data:NSData){
        if self.mCalendarAccountsCallbackContext != nil {            
            
            var list:JSONArray = WmUtils.getJSONArrayFromNSData(data) // dummy data
            var pluginResult:CDVPluginResult = CDVPluginResult(status: CDVCommandStatus_OK, messageAsArray: list)
            pluginResult.setKeepCallbackAsBool(false)
            self.commandDelegate.sendPluginResult(pluginResult, callbackId:self.mCalendarAccountsCallbackContext)
        }
    }


}
```