# Cordova Plugin written in Swift is not calling plugin via cordova.exec()

Tags: cordova, swift, cordova-plugins, cordova-ios

I added CordovaLib 3.8.0 to a Swift project (as a standalone web view (Cleaver) as opposed to an entirely Cordova-based project). To do so, I followed the instructions on the PhoneGap site and then I created and added the following briding header:

```
//  Cordova-Bridging-Header.h

#import <Cordova/CDV.h>
```

I then created a simple plugin:

```
// HelloPlugin.swift

import Foundation

@objc(HelloPlugin) class HelloPlugin: CDVPlugin {


    override func pluginInitialize() {

        super.pluginInitialize();

    }


    func sayHello( command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand ) {

        let pluginResult = CDVPluginResult(status: CDVCommandStatus_OK, messageAsString: "hello");

        commandDelegate.sendPluginResult( pluginResult, callbackId: command.callbackId );

    }


}
```

And then I added it to my config.xml

```
// config.xml

[...]

<feature name="HelloPlugin">
    <param name="ios-package" value="HelloPlugin" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
```

When I run my app (in the simulator), I see that both cordova and the plugin are loading:

```
2015-04-07 20:28:09.277 Test[32687:4349827] Apache Cordova native platform version 3.8.0 is starting.
2015-04-07 20:28:09.278 Test[32687:4349827] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2015-04-07 20:28:09.279 Test[32687:4349827] Unlimited access to network resources
2015-04-07 20:28:09.362 Test[32687:4349827] [CDVTimer][helloplugin] 0.042975ms
2015-04-07 20:28:09.362 Test[32687:4349827] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 0.176013ms
```

However, if I go into the JS console through safari and try to call my sayHello function I get nothing back.

```
// JS (ran manually on console)

cordova.exec(

  // success
  function(){

    console.log( 'success ->', this, arguments );

  }, 

  // failure
  function(){

    console.log( 'fail ->', this, arguments );

  }, 

  // plugin name
  'HelloPlugin',

  // method name
  'sayHello', 

  // arguments
  ['a', 'b', 2]

);
```

I then went into CDVViewController.m and put a breakpoint in the URL scheme handler:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL* url = [request URL];

    /*
     * Execute any commands queued with cordova.exec() on the JS side.
     * The part of the URL after gap:// is irrelevant.
     */
    if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"gap"]) {
```

I found that this code is not being called at all when I execute cordova.exec(). I put a breakpoint in the same spot in an Objective-C project I have that uses Cordova in basically the same way, and the breakpoint fires.

Is there anything I'm missing or should try?

Comment: I think swift plugins aren't supported yet

Comment: @jcesarmobile there are many examples of swift plugins.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25448976/how-to-write-cordova-plugin-in-swifthttp://chrisdell.info/blog/writing-ios-cordova-plugin-pure-swift/

Comment: did you make this changes to your project? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7428

Comment: @jcesarmobile the only difference there is that my deployment target was not 7.0. I changed it to 7.0 but still nothing. I don't think this is an issue with the plugin. The breakpoint I added should get triggered even with an empty cordova.exec() call. It's like the URI scheme handler is not getting registered properly or something.

Comment: I wrote a blog post on writing plugins in Swift and recently published an update for Swift 3 / Xcode 8.2: https://medium.com/modus-create-front-end-development/writing-a-cordova-plugin-in-swift-3-for-ios-e314acf68a47#.1xxihldrj

Comment: Did you ever found a solution for this issue?

Comment: @bartoss yeah. I ditched Cordova and wrote a very lightweight web item bridge on top of WKWebView. It's a lot faster and it was very easy to write. Cordova was too much bloat for what I needed to accomplish.

Comment: I solved my problem. I was having the issue that the swift file was not part of 'compile source file' in the app build settings.

Comment: I do am interested in your project. Do you got any reference/blog about the bridge you wrote?

Comment: @bartosss - something similar to this: https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge It really is pretty easy to put together.